# can not display image from jsp file

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to display image from jsp file, below it is shown, and directory in java file : webapp/webresources/images/img.jpg.   And jsp files also in webapp folder: webapp/index.jsp.

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value = "/webresources/styles/style.css"/>" />
      
</head>
<body>[enter image description here][1]
    
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webresources/images/eclipse.png" alt="photo"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try  using src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/eclipse.png"  or   src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/img.png"